# How do I get the Transform Panel to show?

Tags: panel

I've tried Object and Edit mode ... but somehow the Transform panel does not show up - how do I get the panel to show up so that I can numerically enter transform values?

Comment: press `N` in *Object Mode*

Comment: Or go into the Properties panel > Object > Transform

Comment: ahhh it's a popout >.< getting used to this interface after 3ds max and unity...

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your cursor to the normal cursor, then you can transform

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.